# FirebaseException in ref.updateChildren(): Path X is an ancestor of X/Y in an update

Tags: java, android, firebase

When trying to perform a multi-path write using path like "`users/user`" and "`users/user/name`" in the same `ref.updatChildren()` operation, app crashes with the following exception:

> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Path X is an ancestor of X/Y in
>   an update.

What is the best way to perform this kind of multi-path writes in Firebase? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
In this particular case I wanted to achieve something like:

```
HashMap<String, Object> userUpdate = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
user.put("firstName", "Ivan");
user.put("initialOfLastName", "V");

userUpdate.put("/user", user);
userUpdate.put("/user/gender", "male")

ref.updateChildren(userUpdate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Like the error states, you can't specify an update for `/user` and then specify a different update for `/user/gender`. Moving the gender update to the `user` map should work.

```
user.put("firstName", "Ivan");
user.put("initialOfLastName", "V");
user.put("gender", "male")

userUpdate.put("/user", user);

ref.updateChildren(userUpdate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this will work if the field is String. For complex/nested data,  solution is to put map with "gender" as write path

Comment: If the field isn't a string, then use `HashMap<String, Object>` instead of `HashMap<String, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like that, you'll have to use a nested `HashMap` at the top-level of the location you're updating.

```
HashMap<String,String> userUpdate = new HashMap<String,String>();
userUpdate.put("firstName", "Ivan");
userUpdate.put("initialOfLastName", "V");
ref.child(uid).updateChildren(userUpdate);
```

Comment: With that edit, Anid's answer is the correct one. I'll also retract my close vote. :-)