# Need Solution when getting DatabaseException: Path is an ancestor in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following up on a similliar question like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039860/firebaseexception-in-ref-updatechildren-path-x-is-an-ancestor-of-x-y-in-an-up) one, I just want to get an answer if this is a limitation in `FirebaseDatabase.updateChildren`or if I do something wrong.

I understand I cannot specify an update for /USER and then specify a different update for /USER/ + getUid() + "/" + "fancy" + "/" + pushKey

If I still need this two updates to be atomic what should I do?

```
 childUpdates.put(USER + "/" + getUid(), map1);
 childUpdates.put(USER + "/" + getUid() + "/" + "fancy" + "/" + pushKey, map2);
 // Do a deep-path update
 ref.updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionLi....
```

UPDATE adding clarification:

The values are Strings
this is map1

```
//
// FAN_OUT - User.LAST_VISITED_ADDRESS
//
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map1.put("last_visited_address", "pushKey");
```

this is map2

```
//
// FAN_OUT - User.FANCY
//
Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap();
map2.put("owner", "a path");
```

Comment: You are updating two conflicting nodes here: one being a child of the other.

It's impossible to say how to fix this without seeing the actual keys in `map1` and `map2`.

Comment: Thanks I updated my Q with keys in map1 and map2

Answer (score 5):

When you run a multi-location update statement, the Firebase Database loops over the map you provide. For each entry it updates the location/key with the value you provided. The order in which the entries are executed is unspecified.

This means that if you have two conflicting keys/paths, it is undetermined what the result will be. E.g.

```
/path/to/object        { name: "Erik Hellberg" }
/path/to/object/id     6820170
```

If the server would execute the operations in the order I have them above, the result would be:

```
path
  to
    object
      id   : 6820170
      name: "Erik Hellberg"
```

But if it happened to execute them in the reverse order, the result would be:

```
path
  to
    object
      id   : 6820170
```

Since an indeterministic operation is pretty useless, the Database rejects the update.

Deterministic ways to get the result are:

```
/path/to/object        { id: 6820170, name: "Erik Hellberg" }
```

And:

```
/path/to/object/name   "Erik Hellberg"
/path/to/object/id     6820170
```

Since there is no overlap in update paths here, there is no conflict.

Comment: It´s good to know thanks I figure this was the reason..A solution might be that I run the `map2` separately after `updateChildren` have returned positively for `map1` ok, what you think? , in real life there are also `map3`, `map4` for this particular `updateChildren`

Comment: yea why not this is working, just need two round-trips to Firebase to get everything in place, using setValue and CompletionListener for map2

Comment: I can't tell you what you need to do. But when you use a multi-location update, you must make sure there are no conflicting paths. One simple way to do that is to only have primitive values in your map, like in my last snippet.